# Как правильно получить всех потомков при работе со связями?

Tags: yii2

Есть модель `Catalog` у модели есть связь

```
public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Catalog::className(), ['parent_id' => 'id'])->where(['hidden' => false])->orderBy('sort_order');
    }
```

Вложенность `Children` может быть какая угодно от 0 до бесконечности но мне надо получить `id` последнего `children` если вложеность трех уровней словно я бы я вот так получил бы `$category->children->children->children->id` 
Вот только как это сделать

Comment: "если вложеность трех уровней" - что конкретно имеется в виду? теряется мысль вопроса из-за отсутствия запятых

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще конечно же сразу знать есть ли у узла дети, чем долбить рекурсиями БД, для этого можно заиметь вспомогательные поля `child` `level` и т.п..., но это всё отдельная тема, вот примерная рекурсия которая вам сейчас нужна:

```
/**
 * @param self $model
 * 
 * @return int PrimaryKey последнего ребёнка
 */
public function lastChildren(self $model = null) : int
{
    if ($model === null) {
        $model = $this;
    }
    if (\is_null($model->children)) {
        return $model->id;
    }
    return $this->lastChildren($model->children);
}
```

Comment: Я пошел по другому все таки постгес база данных и можно использовать деревья.  В дереве хранятся все айдишники от потомка ко всем родителям. проверяю если в дереве айдишник есть работаем нет не работаем.